# Other uses for の?

Tags: grammar, translation, particles, set-phrases, parsing

In this sentence

そうして将校の部屋に行くべく木に登るものの、
窓まで伸びていた木の枝は切られてしまっている

The "の" is followed by a "," So my first guess of it being the feminine version of "よ" doesn't seem correct. Is there a place where it could mean "but?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a specific grammatical construction, where ものの is used after a verb.  The basic meaning is "although, however, even though".

Relevant bilingual entries:

- WWWJDIC via the Monash University mirror
  http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1MUJ%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE
- Weblio EJJE
  https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE
- Eijirō
  https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE
- Wiktionary
  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE
- Jisho.org
  https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE
  → Ignore the sample sentence shown here, it is not correctly illustrating this construction.